# Two ways of making an array in Java

Tags: java

I would like to know what is difference between this two lines of code:

```
double array[] = new double[] {1,2,3,4};
double numbers[] = {1,2,3,4};
```

Can someone explain me that?

Comment: Nothing special. It is Just autoboxing :)

Comment: Java support C-Style curly braces {}. In second one an array of the proper type and length is implicitly created, so both are identical but the second one is shorter.